# Push notification not working after application released on App Store

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I made an app using ionic and fcm plugin for notifications. On development mode everything was working. I also configured my certificate and APNs for distribution. It was working on flight test also. But yesterday my app was accepted at App Store and the push notification are not working when you download the app from App Store. 
Any ideias ?

Comment: Check your firebase push notification certificate not expire.

Comment: @PradipPatel you mean the p12 certificate I created to upload on Firebase ? It’s up to date. Thanks

Comment: open firebase console and check certificate if not expire thank other issue either else you have renew certificate.

Comment: Im getting the same issue did you fixed it?

Comment: Is your issue resolved. If yes, please answer your own question and mark it best.